# GetProcAddress doesn't work for functions other than void

Tags: windows-7, dllimport, getprocaddress

I have a problem with GetProcAddress:
I wrote a simple DLL with just one function in it:

```
extern "C" LRESULT WINAPI Function(HWND Hwnd, UINT Message,
                                   WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    Beep(1000, 1000);
    return CallNextHookEx(0, Message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

When I try to get function's address GetProcAddress fails with the ErrorCode 127 (ERROR_PROC_NOT_FOUND). However, if I use void as the function type it works perfectly. I can't really figure out why it behaves like this. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

BTW: DependencyWalker shows that the function's name is indeed "Function" no changes have been applied.

Answer (score 4):

There are only two failure modes for GetProcAddress:

- you didn't export the function
- you didn't get the name right

The exported named of this function is not "Function" unless you used a .def file to rename the export or created a 64-bit DLL.  It will be "_Function@16" for a 32-bit build.  The @16 postfix would be strongly associated with the fact that you have trouble making it work for functions with any arguments.

From the Visual Studio Command Prompt run Dumpbin.exe /exports on your DLL to see the exports.  Delete a .pdb file in the same directory if there is one.

Comment: Hm, tried importing "_Function@16", "_Function@32" and "_Function@64", but it didn't work.... I experimented a litte and now it gets really weird. When I change the functions type from LPARAM WINAPI to void, GetProcAddress works fine for all function names, even stuff like "abc" although those functions don't exist! If I use the original type though GetProcAddress doesn't work!

Comment: Not using WINAPI makes a *big* difference, that disables __stdcall and stops the @ postfix.  Running dumpbin.exe /exports is essential to find the real name, don't skip it.

Comment: I'm using Code::Blocks together with MinGW64, so I'm not able to; are there any alternatives?

Comment: Just ran DependencyWalker again with the current DLL and now it showed "Function@16" (without "_"). I tried importing that and it worked. I have one question left though: Why does my function run in 16bit?

Comment: It doesn't.  @16 is the size of the stack activation frame.  4 arguments that are each 32 bits (4 bytes), 4 x 4 = 16.

Answer (score 2):

It's good idea to use module definition (.def file) with names of exported functions instead of __declspec(dllexport). It's much easier to manage them.

Also this

`#define DllExport extern "C" __declspec (dllexport)`

causes that exported dll function names are without any c++ "decorations"